# YII: How to use "with" and sort at the same time?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I've got a problem on YII relation tables.

As the title says, I just want to combine table "A" with table "B" and sort the combined table according to the "clickTimes" in table "B".

```
        $A = self::find()
        -> with(['B'=>['order'=>'clickTimes DESC']])
        -> all();
```

The above is what I've learned from the Internet but it didn't work. The error goes below.

```
PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members
```

The relation works fine except for the sorting. Any suggestion? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use CDbCriteria like this:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->with = array('foreign_table1', 'foreign_table2',  'foreign_table2.foreign_table3');
$criteria->order = 'foreign_table3.col5 DESC';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use with and order  function in proper way

```
  $A = self::find()
    -> with('your_relation_name')
    ->orderBy(['table_name.attribute'=>SORT_DESC])
    ->all();
```

Comment: :( It doesn't work either. I write like this:`$A= self::find()
    -> with(['relation_name'])
    -> orderBy(['table_name.clickTimes'=>SORT_DESC])
    -> all();`

Comment: The error says:`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'table_name.clickTimes' in 'order clause'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `A` ORDER BY `table_name`.`clickTimes` DESC`